# Website logo alteration/modification/addition

Tags: logo

We are going to reach 10 million users on our site quickly. We were hoping to honor that achievement by adding something to the logo that nods to it. Like a badge '10 million users' added to our site logo.

Does anyone have any examples of sites that have added onto their logo (other than 'Beta')?

Comment: Would help to see the logo. Or at least see a description of what your logo looks like (is it text? graphic?)

Comment: Do you have a designer in-house or on contract? If they can't be trusted to make this update, find a new one.

Comment: Are we supposed to take this seriously? (Especially with such an avatar?) Aspiring to get such number of visitors is good, but don't just assume so.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Doodles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_doodles#Google_Doodle) are one example of modification.